# SQLite iOS error

Tags: ios, sqlite

Im am using SQLite with my iOS app. I am storing a few strings. Here is my query:

```
CustomTableView[312:26534] INSERT INTO Game (name, developer, iconPath) 
VALUES ("2048", "ketchapp","/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9778669B-D84B-
4D15-932E-DEB741FC8093/Documents/cached.png") WHERE id = 1
```

It is throwing this error:

```
2014-11-18 19:49:36.220 CustomTableView[312:26534] near "WHERE": syntax error
```

What is wrong?

Comment: There is no `WHERE` clause on `INSERT`.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: (Did you mean to do `UPDATE`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `WHERE` clause on `INSERT`.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

You probably meant to do `UPDATE`.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html